# Rails - Add attributes not in model and update model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, accessor

I have 3 fields in my form witch are not in my database: opening_type, opening_hours, opening_minutes. I want to update the main attribute "opening" (in database) with these 3 fields.

I tried lot of things that doesn't work.

Actually I have:

```
  attr_accessor :opening_type, :opening_hours, :opening_minutes

  def opening_type=(opening_type)
  end
  def opening_type
    opening_type = opening.split("-")[0] if !opening.blank?
  end

  def opening_hours=(opening_hours)
  end
  def opening_hours
    opening_hours = opening.split("-")[1] if !opening.blank?
  end  

  def opening_minutes=(opening_minutes)
  end
  def opening_minutes
    opening_minutes = opening.split("-")[2] if !opening.blank?    
  end
```

I tried adding something like:

```
  def opening=(opening)
    logger.info "WRITE"

    if !opening_type.blank? and !opening_hours.blank? and opening_minutes.blank?
      opening = ""
      opening << opening_type if !opening_type.blank?
      opening << "-" 
      opening << opening_hours if !opening_hours.blank?
      opening << "-" 
      opening << opening_minutes if !opening_minutes.blank?
    end
    write_attribute(:opening, opening)
  end

  def opening
    read_attribute(:opening)
  end
```

But, the accessors methods are not called and I think opening_type, opening_hours, opening_minutes were empty too if the accessors were called...

I think I don't need a before_save callback and should do this rewriting the accessors.

Notes: 
- Rails 3.0.5, 
- opening_type, :opening_hours, :opening_minutes could be empty

EDIT: I updated my code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that `attr_reader`, `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor` are just macros for defining your own methods.

```
# attr_reader(:foo) is the same as:
def foo
  @foo
end

# attr_writer(:foo) is the same as:
def foo=(new_value)
  @foo = new_value
end

# attr_accessor(:foo) is the same as:
attr_reader(:foo)
attr_writer(:foo)
```

At the moment, your setter methods aren't doing anything special, so if you just switch to `attr_accessor` your code will become cleaner.

Your other issue is that your `opening=` method is never being called, and this makes sense because there's nowhere in your code calling it. What you really want is for your opening to be set after all of the individual parts have been set. Now there's no trivial way to do this, but Rails does have a `before_validation` callback where you can put code that runs after values have been set but before the validation runs:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :opening_type, :opening_hours, :opening_minutes

  before_validation :set_opening

  private
  def set_opening
    return unless opening_type && opening_hours && opening_minutes
    self.opening = opening_type + "-" + opening_hours + "-" + opening_minutes
  end
end
```

Comment: Note this answer assumes you only want to store the combined `opening` field in the database. Another approach would be to store the individual components in the database and build the combined string dynamically on demand. Depending on your requirements that may even be a better approach for you.

Comment: I get this database with the opening field. This database sync with a smartphone app and I can't change its structure to store the 3 different fields. ;-) The problem with a before_validation callback is that you don't handle the case when we are going to edit the form... and where I need to truncate the opening field in 3 vars... for the form. I know I can do that manually but I thought there was a better approach to do that with the accessors...

Comment: All true, but your suggestion of overriding `opening=` will break a lot of things. Also, it's a very sketchy idea to have a setter method which totally discards the parameter that's passed in. Better to have a separate method (like my `set_opening`) which makes clear what it's doing. You don't *have* to use before_validation to call that method but I seriously recommend that it is a separate method

Comment: Actually I can read the 3 fields with my code and fill the form. OK, I will use your tip with the before_validation(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
attr_reader :opening_type, :opening_hours, :opening_minutes
```

you need

```
attr_accessor :opening_type, :opening_hours, :opening_minutes
attr_reader :opening_type, :opening_hours, :opening_minutes
```

hf...

// Are :opening_type, :opening_hours, :opening_minutes real fields? If yes then you just need this?

attr_accessor :opening
attr_reader :opening

Comment: No. The real field is "opening" in my database. I need to concat 3 fields sent from my form: opening_type, opening_hours, opening_minuts to fill the main "opening" field. These 3 fields are not in the database. I updated the first post.

Comment: Then accessors are the worng way. You could use them to seperate one string into many oher but not the other way round. You should store these datas in the database and then you could write a `opening` methid to display the concated fields!

Comment: No I can't. I get these database with the opening field. This database sync with a smartphone app and I can't change its structure to store the 3 fields. ;-)

Comment: okay then please add the form you use to submit the data to your post!

Comment: and also post the params hash please