# Expose a has_many relationship through a single text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, accessor

I have a model A that "has many" B.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B
  attr_accessible :title
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :A
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

I want to add a field to my "edit A" form : a textarea in which I will enter my B's `:name` for each line, and on submit, parse the field, and process each line.

The question is, how should I do that ?

### Edit

Following [Rails - Add attributes not in model and update model attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376744/rails-add-attributes-not-in-model-and-update-model-attribute) I have come to this :

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B
  attr_accessible :title

  def my_b
    list = ""
    self.B.each do |b|
      list += "#{b.name}\n"
    end
    logger.debug("Displayed Bs : " + list)
    list
  end

  def my_b=(value)
    logger.debug("Saved Bs : " + value)
    # do my things with the value
  end

end
```

But `def bees=(value)` never seems to be fired.

What am I doing wrong ?

### Edit 2

My actual code is visible here : https://github.com/cosmo0/TeachMTG/blob/edit-deck/app/models/deck.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my. Turns out the problem was not lying in the model, but in the controller... I forgot to add a simple line in the `update` method to assign my POST value to my class field...

Anyway, final solution is this :

In my controller :

```
  def update
    @a.whatever = params[:a][:whatever]
    @a.my_b = params[:a][:my_b]
    @a.save
  end
```

In my model :

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B
  attr_accessible :whatever

  def my_b
    list = ""
    self.B.each do |b|
      list += "#{b.name}\n"
    end
    list
  end

  def my_b=(value)
    # parse the value and save the elements
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an :attr_accessor, like:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B
  attr_accessible :title
  attr_accessor :field_of_happiness

  def field_of_happiness=(value)
    # override the setter method if you want 
  end

  def field_of_happiness(value)
    # override the getter method if you want 
  end
end
```

[Reference: attr_accessor api doc](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor)

It helps you on some way?

Comment: I was actually testing that. As I edited in my question, the setter never seems to be fired.